# Mule Database Select with multiple WHERE * OR * clauses

Tags: mule, mule-connector

I am try to use the Mule Database Connector, Select Operation to run a query with multiple `WHERE * OR *` clauses which are created dynamically from an array.  What is the best way to do this?

Something like:

SQL Query Text:

```
SELECT
  C1,
  C2
FROM T
WHERE C1 = 'A'
OR C1 = 'B'
OR C1 = 'C'
```

Which is created from:

```
payload = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Where payload is of variable length.

I know I can use a Query single operation in a For Each loop, but I would like to use a bulk query for efficiency if possible.

Comment: What is your criteria for 'best'? Try to avoid opinion-based questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: What do you mean by bulk query? There is no bulk select operation in the Database Connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IN clause and joinBy operator for the array elements like

```
#["SELECT
  C1,
  C2
FROM T
WHERE C1 IN (" ++  payload joinBy "," ++ ")"]
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks @AnupamBhusari.  I think I get the idea, but not able to implement.  I used an SQL Query Text like

```
SELECT
  C1,
  C2
FROM T
WHERE C1 IN (:item)
```

and Input Parameters like: 

```
item: payload joinBy ', '
```

but get no results.

This works as expected: 

```
SELECT
  C1,
  C2
FROM T
WHERE C1 IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Your suggestion looks like the full statement is defined in the Input Parameters.  I tried this also, but get an error.

Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: I got the above to work with the full statement in SQL Query Text.